# Insert fatal error function bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error back on my `INSERT` query

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in...

although I am only inserting strings into the table columns which are expecting string values ::  `VARCHAR(255)`

My table looks like this:

```
+---------------+--------------+-----+------+---+--+--+
| id            | int(11)      | NO  | PRI  |   |  |  |
| username      | varchar(45)  | YES | UNI  |   |  |  |
| email_address | varchar(45)  | YES | UNI  |   |  |  |
| password      | varchar(255) | YES |      |   |  |  |
| role          | int(11)      | YES | NULL | 0 |  |  |
| dashboard_id  | int(11)      | YES | NULL |   |  |  |
+---------------+--------------+-----+------+---+--+--+
```

And my Php looks like this...

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $emailAddress, $upassword);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
    $upassword = password_hash($_POST['upassword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $stmt->execute();

    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
```

**UPDATE**

My connection code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in...` would indicate that `$stmt` is false, and therefore your `prepare` hasn't worked.

Comment: I know this already... Any suggestions...?

Comment: Have you checked your connection details?  Tried them using MySQL Workbench or similar other application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***This is working at my local end:-***

***Structure of table:-***

```
Name            Type            Null    Default  Extra
id              int(11)         No      None     AUTO_INCREMENT  Primary Key
user_name       varchar(256)    No      None    
email_address   varchar(256)    No      None
password        varchar(256)    No      None
role            int(11)         Yes     0
dashboard_id    int(11)         Yes     0
```

***Php code:-***

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$conn = new mysqli('*****','***','****','****');
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$_POST['username'] = 'anant'; // i have hard coded for checking
$_POST['email'] = 'anant@gmail.in';// i have hard coded for checking
$_POST['upassword'] = 'anant@123';// i have hard coded for checking
if(!empty(trim($_POST['username'])) && !empty(trim($_POST['email'])) && !empty(trim($_POST['upassword']))){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
 $upassword = password_hash($_POST['upassword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  if($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name,email_address,password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")){

      $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $emailAddress, $upassword);

      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
    }else{
        echo $conn->error;
    }
  $conn->close();
}else{
  echo "form values are not coming";
}
?>
```

***Note:-***

I got the problem, it is about not providing column names inside `prepare()`. When i did `echo $conn->error;` then i got this error `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`.

So when i provided corresponding column name everything fine and started working.

Hope it helps.